# C# XDocument Save copy file and appends edited to end

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

When I'm trying to edit XML Element and save it, it generates copy (with edited element) and appends it to end of file.

```
var localStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("DataFolder\\PlayerData.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, localStore);

var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);

doc.Root.Element("characters").Element("character").SetElementValue("expierence", 10);

doc.Save(stream, SaveOptions.None);
stream.Close();
```

Example output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <characters>
        <character>
            <expierence>0</expierence>
        </character>
    </characters>
</root><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <characters>
        <character>
            <expierence>10</expierence>
        </character>
    </characters>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what you told it to do by passing `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`.
If you want to truncate any existing file, pass `Create`.

For more information, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode).

Comment: When I change it to create, it creates empty document.

Comment: @user2948474: You're right; I didn't notice that you were reading it too.  Call `SetLength(0)` before saving instead.